# haproxy simple backend configuration always returns 404

Tags: linux, haproxy

I'm trying to put 10.43.231.254:80 behind haproxy2.2 but for some reason, haproxy always returns a 404 not found when I attempt to site

I tried copying the example from https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/2-2r1/configuration/config-sections/frontend/ and applying to my setup, but i'm not having much luck

proof that the host that is running haproxy is able to reach 10.43.231.254:80

```
/etc/haproxy$ curl 10.43.231.254:80 | head
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
<title>User&#039;s Blog! &#8211; Just another WordPress site</title>
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="User&#039;s Blog! &raquo; Feed" href="http://10.43.231.254/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="User&#039;s Blog! &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://10.43.231.254/comments/feed/" />
100 30871    0 30871    0     0   502k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  502k
```

I confirm that the service is able to start:

```
:/etc/haproxy$ sudo /usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -S /run/haproxy-master.sock
Proxy http started.
Proxy web_servers started.
[NOTICE] 287/191035 (33578) : New worker #1 (33580) forked
```

And here is my configuration file

```
/etc/haproxy$ cat haproxy.cfg
global
        log stdout format raw local0
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        log /dev/log    local0 debug
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets

defaults
        log     global
        log /dev/log    local0 debug
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http
        mode http
        bind *:80

        default_backend web_servers


backend web_servers
        mode http
        server server1 10.43.231.254:80
```

And here is the 404 error:

```
/etc/haproxy$ curl localhost
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 0):

haproxy doesn't emit a 404 error; changing the listen port to something else resolved the issue